# How to remove an uninstalled package's dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I want to install a package (DigiKam), but it has a lot of dependencies. If I decide I no longer need this software and uninstall it, will the now unnessary dependencies be removed?

If not, how can I do it manually?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use the command `apt-get autoremove`. It will remove packages that are installed as automatic dependencies, but are not depended anymore.

`apt-get` has a flag `--auto-remove` that can be used to automatically remove the automatically installed packages when removing a manually installed package:

```
apt-get remove --auto-remove packagename
```

Certain other tools are also capable of doing this, for example `aptitude` will automatically suggest that you remove the packages that have been orphaned.

The automatically installed packages tracking is built in to apt so the tracking should work no matter which tool you use to install the packages.

Comment: So, the answer would be that it is NOT done automatically on removing the "parent" package, right ?

Comment: It depends on the method you use to remove the parent package. For example aptitude suggests that those packages are removed when you uninstall the parent package. Not all tools do this though.

Comment: You can remove a package and all of its now-no-longer-needed dependencies in one step with `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove package`.

Comment: the difference between autoremove and --auto-remove is a bit unclear. Can i combine them?

Comment: @johnywhy the flag is meant to be a parameter for remove command while the while the auto-remove command is a standalone one. I doubt you can combine them, but I can't check to make sure at the moment.

Answer (score 12):

```
aptitude purge digikam
deborphan
aptitude purge $(deborphan)
```

`deborphan` lists packages which are not used or do not depend. So you can safely uninstall them. I tend to use `purge` as option of `aptitude` because it removes also config files and other stuff.

Comment: When using deborphan it is often necessary to run it a few times in a row, or at least it was in my experience with it.  It seemed to continue to find new stuff.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Someone wrote an improvement to deborphan. But that never made its way into Debian. The algorithm was better and you had it to run only once. Maybe I'd ask the author if he wants to add it again to Debian/Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Maybe I cannot use it, but deborphan usually wants to remove many applications that I actually use, as well as some important system packages.

Comment: `aptitude purge <pkgname>` is very useful for completely obliterating packages that have had a failed/partially successful uninstallation. Their status may be listed by `dpkg -L <pkgname>` as `deinstall` but using `aptitude` will remove them completely from aptitude's database, and lingering files not removed by the failed installation seemed to be removed too.

Answer (score 5):

The Computer Janitor, in the system menu can do this too.

Answer (score 4):

I use [ubuntu tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), it has a very effecient app cleaning utility that has never removed more then it should.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove
```

Only run this.

Install BleachBit from Software Center. When you clean ur system using it, BleachBit will automatically run this command to clean the apt cache.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

This command will provide the name of dependencies. E.g. my system had `chromium-browser-l10n`.

Then enter the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove chromium-browser-l10n
```

It will remove the dependencies completely from your system