# How do I remove Dolphin and all of its dependencies?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, dolphin

i'm running ubuntu 11.04 with unity. Recently i found that Dolphin  file manager and some qt libraries was installed in my distro, i guess it was installed as a dependency along with some QT softwares ( Qbittorent, Smplayer etc.,)

Well  i  can do 'sudo apt-get remove dolphin' but pls.suggest me the best way to remove all the unwanted libraries/dependencies of QT.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Removing a package including no longer needed package dependencies can be done with

```
apt-get remove --autoremove <package>
```

(see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443/remove-uninstalled-package-dependencies/445#445))

However if Dolphin was installed as a dependency of another package, we need to remove this package first.

In case we need to keep any package depending on Dolphin we cannot remove Dolphin.

Comment: Thanks. You are right! This should have come as a dependency while installing **digikam** (Correct me if i'm wrong) anyways removed dolphin, kdebase runtime, akonadi, nepomuk etc...

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Liux Mint xfce with KDE added later), apt wants to also remove my desktop environment! That would be "sub-optimal" for me, so instead a terrible hack:

```
/usr/bin # mv dolphin dolphin_DISABLED
/usr/bin # ln -s nemo dolphin
```

Maybe I will regret this but now `nemo` should open when they asked for a `dolphin`.