# How to remove all installed packages that depends on specific package

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove an uninstalled package's dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443/how-to-remove-an-uninstalled-packages-dependencies)

when I want to install a *specific package* (with synaptic) that depends on some other packages, I have to install them too.

But I want to remove this specific package, I want the dependencies to be removed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you remove the package, any packages that were automatically installed because of their dependency can be removed like this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

From the [`man page`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
>              installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no
>              more needed.