# APT autoremove old packages

Tags: apt

How to autoremove all installed packages and not existed in repositories? Example: after several dist-upgrades there is many libs (libapt-inst1.3  libapt-inst1.4  libapt-inst1.5, great count of libdnsXX etc).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to remove packages that no longer have packages dependent upon it is:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This removes packages that are installed as dependencies, but aren't needed any more.

More information and more answers can be found on this post:

http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/443/how-to-remove-an-uninstalled-packages-dependencies

Hope this helps!