# Why does package size during installation differs from package size reported during removal?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

Let me detail what I try to ask.

When I use

```
sudo apk-get install blablabla
```

I get the output

```
After this operation, 39.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

but when I execute

```
sudo apk-get purge blablabla
```

the output states I'll have 23.4 MB of additional disk space. What creates the difference?

Still new to Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages have something known as dependencies. For example , package `cowsay` depends on `perl` ( and you can verify that with `apt-cache show pkgname`). When you install a package, apt-get installs additional dependencies as well, but when removing a package - apt-get leaves dependencies alone, and [you have to use autoremove option](https://askubuntu.com/a/445/295286)

On the other hand, it also doesn't account for the cache packages, i.e. the actual `.deb` package which `apt` downloads, then extracts stuff from it and compiles.

Check this:

```
$ apt-cache show cowsay | grep -i size
Installed-Size: 88
Size: 18532
```

All`deb` packages have this `Installed-Size` information field which by definition is

> estimated installed size in bytes, divided by 1024 and rounded up

( Notice, it's estimated, it's may vary with the actual amount of installed files, and depend on how meticulous the package maintainer is about the details )
So the estimated installation will be 88*1024 = 90112 or 90.1 kB in size. And it coincides with what `purge` says:

```
After this operation, 90.1 kB disk space will be freed.
```

After I have purged the package, the archive however is still there:

```
$ ls /var/cache/apt/archives/cowsay_3.03+dfsg1-6_all.deb               
/var/cache/apt/archives/cowsay_3.03+dfsg1-6_all.deb
```

You can use `apt-get` flags `clean` and `autoclean` as well as remove those manually

Answer (score 0):

Part of it is because there are configs (now I see you are doing purge), but there's also the cache space used up by the DEB archive when it's downloaded.

Comment: How to completely delete them all?

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean` will (supposedly) clean your cache.